# What is the last version of flyway community edition that supported MySQL 5.7

Tags: version, flyway

I have been using `flyway` community edition `version 5.2.3` for a while now. We just recently tried to upgrade flyway to `version 8.2`.  After upgrading to version 8.2 the execution against `MySQL 5.7` is throwing an `error` stating

> "ERROR: Flyway Teams Edition or MySQL upgrade required: MySQL 5.7 is
> no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported
> by Flyway Teams Edition."

My question is what was the last version of the `flyway` community edition that supported `MySQL 5.7`?

Answer (score 30):

[Flyway Community Edition 8.0.0-beta1](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.0.0-beta1) dropped support for databases older than 5 years, including MySQL 5.7.

The minimum supported version of MySQL was increased from 5.7 to 8.0 in [this commit](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/commit/4622cee057c855a718533d60aecb2c3e21960a5f), which was introduced in [Flyway 8.0.0-beta1](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/86c285e5a707e19700f1c53841af02397323e844/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/mysql/MySQLDatabase.java#L252).

Currently, the latest community edition version that supports MySQL 5.7 is [Flyway 7.15.0](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/e589f3e880f943c22e4fac536e811363a8cfb0b8/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/mysql/MySQLDatabase.java#L255).

Comment: flyway-mysql:7.15.0 was pulled from maven repos. Lowest version 8.2.1

Comment: Just to clarify, there was no `flyway-mysql` prior to 8.2.1. The corresponding code was included in `flyway-core` but was extracted to a separate jar in 8.2.1. See the release notes: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.2.1

Answer (score 6):

This restriction is no longer in place from Flyway version 10 (October 2023).  We have updated Flyway so that it works with ALL supported database versions, so if you upgrade to version 10 you can access all supported versions of MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Just download old version of flyway manually from the website and install it.

Tried installing it from brew using various method, it doesn't work for flyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).