# Flyway version declared in Pom causing conflict

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am upgrading my java to version 17(spring boot version-3.0.4), but I need to use flyway-core dependency as 6.5.7 only as it is the last flyway version available that supports mysql 5.7(which I need to use in my project).
But when I run my junits I get below error:-
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureProperties(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:187)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.failOnMissingLocations(boolean)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/sx8428/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.0.4/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.4.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class
```

The called method's class, org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/sx8428/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/7.5.4/flyway-core-7.5.4.jar!/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/sx8428/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/7.5.4/flyway-core-7.5.4.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration and org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration

I need to find a way to exclude spring from automatically configuring flyway version.

Comment: Can you please also share specific problem that you have when using flyway version compatible with Spring Boot version that you use. Not sure how does this affect mysql version.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 6.5.7 is the last flyway version that supports mysql 5.7. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Spring using FlywayAutoConfiguration, set `spring.flyway.enabled=false` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data-migration)).

If you want to find an older version of FlywayAutoConfiguration that behaves as you want, then try looking through the old versions [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commits/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java) and copy it into you project.
You will need to remove this from your copy:

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.flyway", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
```

Comment: Along with copying the configuration, Do I need to add any dependency too because few imports are not resolved I can see?
Like org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor

Comment: Are you sure you need all this, since when I tried creating a spring boot project, it automatically added an additional dependency on `flyway-mysql`? Do you just need to add this as an extra dependency, so it doesn't seem that it was a part of `flyway-core` anyway? It still seems to be a thing on their website: https://flywaydb.org/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you problem

1. The latest version of Community Flyway that supports MySQL 5.7 is [indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70438180/what-is-the-last-version-of-flyway-community-edition-that-supported-mysql-5-7) 7.15.0
2. The latest version of Spring that supports version of Flyway up to 7.15.0 is [2.5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.5.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L315)

Therefore, what you can do is to use version of Flyway 7.7.3 and copy [flyway folder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/2.5.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway) from that version of Spring to your source code.
Everything else from Spring will be from original version and only Flyway will be replaced.